# Attempting to deploy to heroku, blows up when installing hoe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've got hoe commented out in my Gemfile and my version of rubygems is 2.0+.  Here's the output when I run `git push heroku master`:

```
Installing json (1.7.7)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.1)
       Installing thor (0.17.0)
       Installing railties (3.2.12)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing commonjs (0.2.6)
       Installing formtastic (2.2.1)
       Installing formtastic-bootstrap (2.0.0)
       Installing hoe (3.5.0)
       Gem::InstallError: hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself.
       An error occurred while installing hoe (3.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install hoe -v '3.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:limitless-river-5139.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:limitless-river-5139.git'
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: is it installing hoe or is that dependency off another gem?

Comment: Well, it's a helper for rake but I don't think it's required.

Comment: don't install hoe. it can't possibly be needed in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had several projects in my .git.  Some of them still had the hoe gem.  This was causing the issue.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this fix?
I have explicitly moved the hoe gem to development group in the GemFile and removed development environment from heroku, but am still getting the same error.

Comment: @SumitBisht, I was pretty novice when I worked this out.  What I believe is that when I was updating my git repo I did not use the `-a` option to ensure that deleted files were deleted in the master branch.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!
In my case, I was using the roo gem to parse excel files, which had the dependency of hoe. Removing the roo gem did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following:

```
gem update --system
```

then

```
git push heroku master
```

again.

Comment: was the gem update successful? Is it that you get the same error trying the push to heroku ?

Comment: yea, the gem is installed fine on my machine.